# How Do You Supply Environment Variables to SBT Running in Docker Compose?

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, playframework, sbt

I am attempting to run a Play Framework Scala application via Docker Compose, and I would like to supply environment variables to it. Unfortunately, SBT doesn't pick them up when I do supply them via `environment`:

```
environment:
      - http.port=${PORT}
```

where I have `PORT=1234` in a `.env` file in the same directory.

However, it works just fine when I submit them as part of the command:

```
command: "sbt run -Dhttp.port=${PORT}"
```

I could do it this way in a pinch, but I would rather set the variables within `environment`.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems like it should work.  What is the output of `docker-compose config`?  Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I am seeing `http.port: '1234'`, which is what I want. Not to mention `docker-compose run web env` shows the same. I wonder if this is an SBT thing...

Answer (score 0):

`-Dx=y` is s way to pass a flag to JVM through CLI, but it doesn't mean that JVM expects `y` environment variable.

You correctly defined your variable in command:

```
command: "sbt run -Dhttp.port=${PORT}"
```

which means you have to provide `PORT` variable (not `http.port`!). It should be:

```
environment:
  - PORT=${PORT}
```

or (since the name inside docker and outside [are the same](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers)):

```
environment:
 - PORT
```